# Adding class to span element is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am receiving a large JSON object having large volume of data in ajax success method
but when i am iterating over the JSON list and want add individual class to each element things are not working.

The code snippet i am pasting here is inside ajax success method

```
$.each(data, function(index,jsonObject){
    console.log(jsonObject.spanId+":"+jsonObject.status)
    if(jsonObject.status != null && jsonObject.status != undefined){
        if(jsonObject.status == "Available"){
        $('#'+jsonObject.spanId).addClass("availableTime");
        }else{
        $('#'+jsonObject.spanId).addClass("vacantTime");
        }
    }
});
```

I have tried lot but not able to accomplish, please help me.

I am adding chunk of my json object

```
[
    {
        "spanId": null,
        "status": null
    },
    {
        "spanId": null,
        "status": null
    },
    {
        "spanId": "25_31_15:00",
        "status": "Available"
    },
    {
        "spanId": "25_31_15:30",
        "status": "Available"
    },
    {
        "spanId": "25_31_16:00",
        "status": "Available"
    },
    {
        "spanId": "25_31_16:30",
        "status": "Available"
    },
    {
        "spanId": "25_31_17:00",
        "status": "Available"
    }
]
```

Comment: Provide a chunk of your data or nobody will be able to help you. The jquery addClass method do work.

Comment: Might be because of the `:` that it might not work.

Comment: Despite `:` being invalid here, have you tried `$(document.getElementById(jsonObject.spanId))` instead?

Comment: my answer would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You span ids are [not advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858521/adding-class-to-span-element-is-not-working#comment31292603_20858649) and it may be what is not working.

Plus `:` for selectors is a reserved word for pseudo classes.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1665540)

Comment: Yes unfortunately its not working due to : in the selectors, now i removed it and its working Thanks !!!

Comment: All the rules are in the stackoverflow post i linked in my answer.

Comment: Yea "perfectly" with quotes as you can [escape them in the jquery selector](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/) but it is not advised anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what you might expect, the use of colons in ids is okay, though only HTML5 started to accept ids starting with a digit. For better interoperability, it's recommended to start ids with a letter and not use colons in the first place.

That said, if you must use colons in your identifiers, you must escape them when you use them as part of a selector:

```
$('25_31_17\\:00') // this works fine
```

Alternatively, if you're going to find elements by their identifier, you might also want to consider:

```
$(document.getElementById(jsonObject.spanId)) // this will work too
```

Answer (score 0):

H i, just missing a couple of things and ***data*** is in the wrong place ( by the looks )

try running this  :

```
  $.each(data, function(index){
      console.log(data[index].spanId+":"+data[index].status)

  });
```

notice that you need to tell the loop which array item to reference :

```
  data[index]
```

and that the 'each' is looping over the array:

```
   $.each(data, function(index){ ...
```

EDIT with data ref:

```
  var data =  [
   {
    "spanId": null,
    "status": null
   },
   {
    "spanId": null,
    "status": null
   },
   {
    "spanId": "25_31_15:00",
    "status": "Available"
   },
   {
    "spanId": "25_31_15:30",
    "status": "Available"
   },
   {
    "spanId": "25_31_16:00",
    "status": "Available"
   },
   {
    "spanId": "25_31_16:30",
    "status": "Available"
    },
    {
    "spanId": "25_31_17:00",
    "status": "Available"
    }
   ]
```